In KeycloaK, how do I create a condition that checks if the `x-www-form-urlencoded` request contains `username` and `password`?
I have a project that uses Keycloak for authentication. The Keycloak version is 16 and it's in Java. I have the authentication flow from the image below. I need to add a condition to use the username and password only if they are present; otherwise, it should proceed to the next configured flow. Can someone help me?

